# Reporting Services 2005 / C# Using Report Viewer Access Values of WebForm Controls

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a report viewer that is using form controls to dynamically pick and display the correct report with parameters.  How can I display those form control values, like the textbox text value, in the report when it is rendered?

Thanks for any and all assistance!

Gene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't unless you actually send them in to the report as parameters (strings, ints, etc).
There is no object model reference to use in the report control to the outside controls.